# Is there a way to send chef exit code to shell

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

We are currently calling a chef recipe from a shell script. The chef fails with a custom exit code, something like below. But the shell script gets the exit code as `1`. So can I make shell script fail with this custom exit code.

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 5)
```

Comment: How do you terminate your shell script?

Comment: How do you call your recipe ? What is the purpose of wrapping the chef run within a shell script ? This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. Chef's exit code have specific meanings which you can find documented at https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc062-exit-status.md#exit-codes-in-use

Answer (score 0):

It's abit hacky, try using export/set_env param ...

```
begin
    <yourcode>
rescue
    env 'error_code' do
      value '5'
    end
end
```

and then access that env param and delete it.